# Turn off phantomjs messages when running a casperjs script

Tags: phantomjs, casperjs

I am running the basic script with casperjs:

http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html

I see that my console output shows the following additional messages from phantomjs apart from the page's titles :

> 2014-01-28 15:14:01.150 phantomjs[19493:110b] *** WARNING: Method userSpaceScaleFactor in class NSView is deprecated on 10.7 and later. It should not be used in new applications. Use convertRectToBacking: instead.
>
> 2014-01-28 15:14:04.050 phantomjs[19493:110b] CoreText performance note: Client called CTFontCreateWithName() using name "Palatino" and got font with PostScript name "Palatino-Roman". For best performance, only use PostScript names when calling this API.
>
> 2014-01-28 15:14:04.050 phantomjs[19493:110b] CoreText performance note: Set a breakpoint on CTFontLogSuboptimalRequest to debug.

Is there a way to turn these off so I can get a clean output?

Comment: Log message show a bug with phantomjs : https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/11612 did you try to run your script with slimerjs?

Comment: Have not tried with slimerjs but would prefer using Phantomjs and see a way to separate the casperjs logs from the phantomjs console logs

Comment: Didn't see a problem with slimerjs. Getting a cleaner output

Comment: perhaps [this](https://github.com/nathanboktae/mocha-phantomjs/issues/133) adds to the topic.